# OrderBy () it is not working properly on some columns

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I have the following code inside my asp.net mvc controller's action method:-

```
racks = repository.AllFindRacks_j(withOutSpace).OrderBy(a => a.DataCenter.Name)
                    .ToPagedList(page, pagesize);
```

which will call the following 2 repository methods:-

```
    public IQueryable<ITRack> AllFindRacks_j(string q, bool forautocomplete = false)
            {return from rack in ITRacksCore().Where(a => a.Technology.Tag.ToUpper().StartsWith(q.ToUpper()) || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(q)))
select rack;}


    public IQueryable<ITRack> ITRacksCore()
            {
                return IT.ITRacks.Include(rack => rack.DataCenter).Include(rack => rack.Zone).Include(rack => rack.ITFirewalls).Include(rack => rack.ITRouters).Include(rack => rack.ITServers).Include(rack => rack.ITStorageDevices).Include(rack => rack.ITSwitches).Include(rack => rack.Technology.TechnologyType);
            }
```

Simply i was expecting that the result will be ordered by the Datacenter.Name, but what i got is that the records were not be ordered by the datacenter name, and i can not determine the pattern for the returned results. Although i have used the same approach for sorting the records based on other columns and the orderby is working well. can anyone advice what might be the problem ?
**Edit**
This is the generated sql statement after doing a sort:-

```
   exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
            //code goes here
    [UnionAll2].[C77] AS [C77], 
    [UnionAll2].[C78] AS [C78], 
    [UnionAll2].[C79] AS [C79]
    FROM  (SELECT 
    [UnionAll1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [UnionAll1].[Name] AS [C2], 
    [UnionAll1].[TechnologyID] AS [C3], 
    [UnionAll1].[ITRackID] AS [C4], 
    [UnionAll1].[ID] AS [C5], 
    //code goes here
    [UnionAll1].[C38] AS [C78], 
                        [UnionAll1].[C39] AS [C79]
                        FROM  (SELECT 
                            CASE WHEN ([Extent6].[FirewallID] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1], 
                            [Limit1].[Name] AS [Name], 
                            //code goes here, 
                            CAST(NULL AS bigint) AS [C38], 
                            CAST(NULL AS varbinary(1)) AS [C39]
                            FROM   (SELECT TOP (15) [Project1].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID], [Project1].[DataCenterID] AS [DataCenterID], [Project1].[ZoneID] AS [ZoneID], [Project1].[timestamp] AS [timestamp], [Project1].[IT360SiteID] AS [IT360SiteID], [Project1].[TechnologyID] AS [TechnologyID], [Project1].[Tag] AS [Tag], [Project1].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], [Project1].[timestamp1] AS [timestamp1], [Project1].[TypeID] AS [TypeID], [Project1].[StartDate] AS [StartDate], [Project1].[IT360ID] AS [IT360ID], [Project1].[IsCompleted] AS [IsCompleted], [Project1].[PartialTag] AS [PartialTag], [Project1].[ID] AS [ID], [Project1].[Name] AS [Name], [Project1].[timestamp2] AS [timestamp2], [Project1].[ZoneID1] AS [ZoneID1], [Project1].[Name1] AS [Name1], [Project1].[DataCenterID1] AS [DataCenterID1], [Project1].[AssetTypeID] AS [AssetTypeID], [Project1].[Name2] AS [Name2], [Project1].[IncludedInSearch] AS [IncludedInSearch]
                                FROM ( SELECT [Project1].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID], [Project1].[DataCenterID] AS [DataCenterID], [Project1].[ZoneID] AS [ZoneID], [Project1].[timestamp] AS [timestamp], [Project1].[IT360SiteID] AS [IT360SiteID], [Project1].[TechnologyID] AS [TechnologyID], [Project1].[Tag] AS [Tag], [Project1].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], [Project1].[timestamp1] AS [timestamp1], [Project1].[TypeID] AS [TypeID], [Project1].[StartDate] AS [StartDate], [Project1].[IT360ID] AS [IT360ID], [Project1].[IsCompleted] AS [IsCompleted], [Project1].[PartialTag] AS [PartialTag], [Project1].[ID] AS [ID], [Project1].[Name] AS [Name], [Project1].[timestamp2] AS [timestamp2], [Project1].[ZoneID1] AS [ZoneID1], [Project1].[Name1] AS [Name1], [Project1].[DataCenterID1] AS [DataCenterID1], [Project1].[AssetTypeID] AS [AssetTypeID], [Project1].[Name2] AS [Name2], [Project1].[IncludedInSearch] AS [IncludedInSearch], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Project1].[Name] ASC) AS [row_number]
                                    FROM ( SELECT 
                                        [Extent1].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID], 
                                        [Extent1].[DataCenterID] AS [DataCenterID], 
                                        [Extent1].[ZoneID] AS [ZoneID], 
                                        [Extent1].[timestamp] AS [timestamp], 
                                        [Extent1].[IT360SiteID] AS [IT360SiteID], 
                                        [Extent2].[TechnologyID] AS [TechnologyID], 
                                        [Extent2].[Tag] AS [Tag], 
                                        [Extent2].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], 
                                        [Extent2].[timestamp] AS [timestamp1], 
                                        [Extent2].[TypeID] AS [TypeID], 
                                        [Extent2].[StartDate] AS [StartDate], 
                                        [Extent2].[IT360ID] AS [IT360ID], 
                                        [Extent2].[IsCompleted] AS [IsCompleted], 
                                        [Extent2].[PartialTag] AS [PartialTag], 
                                        [Extent3].[ID] AS [ID], 
                                        [Extent3].[Name] AS [Name], 
                                        [Extent3].[timestamp] AS [timestamp2], 
                                        [Extent4].[ZoneID] AS [ZoneID1], 
                                        [Extent4].[Name] AS [Name1], 
                                        [Extent4].[DataCenterID] AS [DataCenterID1], 
                                        [Extent5].[AssetTypeID] AS [AssetTypeID], 
                                        [Extent5].[Name] AS [Name2], 
                                        [Extent5].[IncludedInSearch] AS [IncludedInSearch]
                                        FROM     [dbo].[ITRacks] AS [Extent1]
                                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Technology] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ITRackID] = [Extent2].[TechnologyID]
                                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[DataCenter] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[DataCenterID] = [Extent3].[ID]
                                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Zones] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent1].[ZoneID] = [Extent4].[ZoneID]
                                        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[TechnologyTypes] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent2].[TypeID] = [Extent5].[AssetTypeID]
                                        WHERE (@p__linq__0 IS NULL) OR (( CAST(LEN(@p__linq__0) AS int)) = 0) OR (( CAST(CHARINDEX(UPPER(@p__linq__1), UPPER([Extent2].[Tag])) AS int)) = 1)
                                    )  AS [Project1]
                                )  AS [Project1]
                                WHERE [Project1].[row_number] > 0
                                ORDER BY [Project1].[Name] ASC ) AS [Limit1]
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ITFirewalls] AS [Extent6] ON [Limit1].[ITRackID] = [Extent6].[RackID]
                        UNION ALL
                            SELECT 
                            2 AS [C1], 
                            [Limit2].[Name] AS [Name], 
                            [Limit2].[TechnologyID] AS [TechnologyID], 
                            [Limit2].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID], 
                            [Limit2].[ID] AS [ID], 
                            [Limit2].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID1], 
                            [Limit2].[TechnologyID] AS [TechnologyID1], 
                            [Limit2].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID2], 
                            [Limit2].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID3], 
                            [Limit2].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID4], 
                            [Limit2].[DataCenterID] AS [DataCenterID], 
                            [Limit2].[ZoneID] AS [ZoneID], 
                            [Limit2].[timestamp] AS [timestamp], 
                            [Limit2].[IT360SiteID] AS [IT360SiteID], 
                            [Limit2].[ID] AS [ID1], 
                            [Limit2].[Name] AS [Name1], 
                            [Limit2].[timestamp2] AS [timestamp1], 
                            [Limit2].[ZoneID1] AS [ZoneID1], 
                            [Limit2].[Name1] AS [Name2], 
                            [Limit2].[DataCenterID1] AS [DataCenterID1], 
                            [Limit2].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID5], 
                            [Limit2].[TechnologyID] AS [TechnologyID2], 
                            [Limit2].[Tag] AS [Tag], 
                            [Limit2].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], 
                            [Limit2].[timestamp1] AS [timestamp2], 
                            [Limit2].[TypeID] AS [TypeID], 
                            [Limit2].[StartDate] AS [StartDate], 
                            [Limit2].[IT360ID] AS [IT360ID], 
                            [Limit2].[IsCompleted] AS [IsCompleted], 
                            [Limit2].[PartialTag] AS [PartialTag], 
                            [Limit2].[AssetTypeID] AS [AssetTypeID], 
                            [Limit2].[Name2] AS [Name3], 
                            [Limit2].[IncludedInSearch] AS [IncludedInSearch], 
                            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C2], 
                            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C3], 
                            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C4], 
                            CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C5], 
                            CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C6], 
                            CAST(NULL AS varbinary(1)) AS [C7], 
                            CAST(NULL AS bigint) AS [C8], 
                            CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C9], 
                            [Extent12].[RouterID] AS [RouterID], 
                            [Extent12].[ModelID] AS [ModelID], 
                            [Extent12].[RackID] AS [RackID], 
                            [Extent12].[Description] AS [Description], 
                            [Extent12].[ConsoleServerID] AS [ConsoleServerID], 
                            [Extent12].[ConsoleServerIPIn] AS [ConsoleServerIPIn], 
                            [Extent12].[ConsoleServerIPOut] AS [ConsoleServerIPOut], 
                            [Extent12].[Spec] AS [Spec], 
                            [Extent12].[timestamp] AS [timestamp3], 
                            [Extent12].[IT360SiteID] AS [IT360SiteID1], 
                            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C10], 
                            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C11], 
                            CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C12], 
                            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C13], 
                            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C14], 
                            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C15], 
                            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C16], 
                            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C17], 
                            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C18], 
                            CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C19], 
                            CAST(NULL AS varbinary(1)) AS [C20], 
                            CAST(NULL AS bigint) AS [C21], 
                            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C22], 
                            CAST(NULL AS decimal(8,2)) AS [C23], 
                            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C24], 
                            CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C25], 
                            CAST(NULL AS varbinary(1)) AS [C26], 
                            CAST(NULL AS bigint) AS [C27], 
                            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C28], 
                            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C29], 
                            CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C30], 
                            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C31], 
                            CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C32], 
                            CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C33], 
                            CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C34], 
                            CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C35], 
                            CAST(NULL AS bigint) AS [C36], 
                            CAST(NULL AS varbinary(1)) AS [C37]
                            FROM   (SELECT TOP (15) [Project3].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID], [Project3].[DataCenterID] AS [DataCenterID], [Project3].[ZoneID] AS [ZoneID], [Project3].[timestamp] AS [timestamp], [Project3].[IT360SiteID] AS [IT360SiteID], [Project3].[TechnologyID] AS [TechnologyID], [Project3].[Tag] AS [Tag], [Project3].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], [Project3].[timestamp1] AS [timestamp1], [Project3].[TypeID] AS [TypeID], [Project3].[StartDate] AS [StartDate], [Project3].[IT360ID] AS [IT360ID], [Project3].[IsCompleted] AS [IsCompleted], [Project3].[PartialTag] AS [PartialTag], [Project3].[ID] AS [ID], [Project3].[Name] AS [Name], [Project3].[timestamp2] AS [timestamp2], [Project3].[ZoneID1] AS [ZoneID1], [Project3].[Name1] AS [Name1], [Project3].[DataCenterID1] AS [DataCenterID1], [Project3].[AssetTypeID] AS [AssetTypeID], [Project3].[Name2] AS [Name2], [Project3].[IncludedInSearch] AS [IncludedInSearch]
                                FROM ( SELECT [Project3].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID], [Project3].[DataCenterID] AS [DataCenterID], [Project3].[ZoneID] AS [ZoneID], [Project3].[timestamp] AS [timestamp], [Project3].[IT360SiteID] AS [IT360SiteID], [Project3].[TechnologyID] AS [TechnologyID], [Project3].[Tag] AS [Tag], [Project3].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], [Project3].[timestamp1] AS [timestamp1], [Project3].[TypeID] AS [TypeID], [Project3].[StartDate] AS [StartDate], [Project3].[IT360ID] AS [IT360ID], [Project3].[IsCompleted] AS [IsCompleted], [Project3].[PartialTag] AS [PartialTag], [Project3].[ID] AS [ID], [Project3].[Name] AS [Name], [Project3].[timestamp2] AS [timestamp2], [Project3].[ZoneID1] AS [ZoneID1], [Project3].[Name1] AS [Name1], [Project3].[DataCenterID1] AS [DataCenterID1], [Project3].[AssetTypeID] AS [AssetTypeID], [Project3].[Name2] AS [Name2], [Project3].[IncludedInSearch] AS [IncludedInSearch], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Project3].[Name] ASC) AS [row_number]
                                    FROM ( SELECT 
                                        [Extent7].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID], 
                                        [Extent7].[DataCenterID] AS [DataCenterID], 
                                        [Extent7].[ZoneID] AS [ZoneID], 
                                        [Extent7].[timestamp] AS [timestamp], 
                                        [Extent7].[IT360SiteID] AS [IT360SiteID], 
                                        [Extent8].[TechnologyID] AS [TechnologyID], 
                                        [Extent8].[Tag] AS [Tag], 
                                        [Extent8].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], 
                                        [Extent8].[timestamp] AS [timestamp1], 
                                        [Extent8].[TypeID] AS [TypeID], 
                                        [Extent8].[StartDate] AS [StartDate], 
                                        [Extent8].[IT360ID] AS [IT360ID], 
                                        [Extent8].[IsCompleted] AS [IsCompleted], 
                                        [Extent8].[PartialTag] AS [PartialTag], 
                                        [Extent9].[ID] AS [ID], 
        //code goes here
                        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C20], 
                        CAST(NULL AS decimal(8,2)) AS [C21], 
                        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C22], 
                        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C23], 
                        CAST(NULL AS varbinary(1)) AS [C24], 
                        CAST(NULL AS bigint) AS [C25], 
                        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C26], 
                        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C27], 
                        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C28], 
                        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C29], 
                        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C30], 
                        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C31], 
                        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C32], 
                        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C33], 
                        CAST(NULL AS bigint) AS [C34], 
                        CAST(NULL AS varbinary(1)) AS [C35]
                        FROM   (SELECT TOP (15) [Project6].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID], [Project6].[DataCenterID] AS [DataCenterID], [Project6].[ZoneID] AS [ZoneID], [Project6].[timestamp] AS [timestamp], [Project6].[IT360SiteID] AS [IT360SiteID], [Project6].[TechnologyID] AS [TechnologyID], [Project6].[Tag] AS [Tag], [Project6].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], [Project6].[timestamp1] AS [timestamp1], [Project6].[TypeID] AS [TypeID], [Project6].[StartDate] AS [StartDate], [Project6].[IT360ID] AS [IT360ID], [Project6].[IsCompleted] AS [IsCompleted], [Project6].[PartialTag] AS [PartialTag], [Project6].[ID] AS [ID], [Project6].[Name] AS [Name], [Project6].[timestamp2] AS [timestamp2], [Project6].[ZoneID1] AS [ZoneID1], [Project6].[Name1] AS [Name1], [Project6].[DataCenterID1] AS [DataCenterID1], [Project6].[AssetTypeID] AS [AssetTypeID], [Project6].[Name2] AS [Name2], [Project6].[IncludedInSearch] AS [IncludedInSearch]
                            FROM ( SELECT [Project6].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID], [Project6].[DataCenterID] AS [DataCenterID], [Project6].[ZoneID] AS [ZoneID], [Project6].[timestamp] AS [timestamp], [Project6].[IT360SiteID] AS [IT360SiteID], [Project6].[TechnologyID] AS [TechnologyID], [Project6].[Tag] AS [Tag], [Project6].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], [Project6].[timestamp1] AS [timestamp1], [Project6].[TypeID] AS [TypeID], [Project6].[StartDate] AS [StartDate], [Project6].[IT360ID] AS [IT360ID], [Project6].[IsCompleted] AS [IsCompleted], [Project6].[PartialTag] AS [PartialTag], [Project6].[ID] AS [ID], [Project6].[Name] AS [Name], [Project6].[timestamp2] AS [timestamp2], [Project6].[ZoneID1] AS [ZoneID1], [Project6].[Name1] AS [Name1], [Project6].[DataCenterID1] AS [DataCenterID1], [Project6].[AssetTypeID] AS [AssetTypeID], [Project6].[Name2] AS [Name2], [Project6].[IncludedInSearch] AS [IncludedInSearch], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Project6].[Name] ASC) AS [row_number]
                                FROM ( SELECT 
                                    [Extent13].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID], 
                                    [Extent13].[DataCenterID] AS [DataCenterID], 
                                    [Extent13].[ZoneID] AS [ZoneID], 
                                    [Extent13].[timestamp] AS [timestamp], 
                                    [Extent13].[IT360SiteID] AS [IT360SiteID], 
                                    [Extent14].[TechnologyID] AS [TechnologyID], 
                                    [Extent14].[Tag] AS [Tag], 
                                    [Extent14].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], 
                                    [Extent14].[timestamp] AS [timestamp1], 
                                    [Extent14].[TypeID] AS [TypeID], 
                                    [Extent14].[StartDate] AS [StartDate], 
                                    [Extent14].[IT360ID] AS [IT360ID], 
                                    [Extent14].[IsCompleted] AS [IsCompleted], 
                                    [Extent14].[PartialTag] AS [PartialTag], 
                                    [Extent15].[ID] AS [ID], 
                                    [Extent15].[Name] AS [Name], 
                                    [Extent15].[timestamp] AS [timestamp2], 
                                    [Extent16].[ZoneID] AS [ZoneID1], 
                                    [Extent16].[Name] AS [Name1], 
                                    [Extent16].[DataCenterID] AS [DataCenterID1], 
                                    [Extent17].[AssetTypeID] AS [AssetTypeID], 
                                    [Extent17].[Name] AS [Name2], 
                                    [Extent17].[IncludedInSearch] AS [IncludedInSearch]
                                    FROM     [dbo].[ITRacks] AS [Extent13]
                                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Technology] AS [Extent14] ON [Extent13].[ITRackID] = [Extent14].[TechnologyID]
                                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[DataCenter] AS [Extent15] ON [Extent13].[DataCenterID] = [Extent15].[ID]
                                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Zones] AS [Extent16] ON [Extent13].[ZoneID] = [Extent16].[ZoneID]
                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[TechnologyTypes] AS [Extent17] ON [Extent14].[TypeID] = [Extent17].[AssetTypeID]
                                    WHERE (@p__linq__0 IS NULL) OR (( CAST(LEN(@p__linq__0) AS int)) = 0) OR (( CAST(CHARINDEX(UPPER(@p__linq__1), UPPER([Extent14].[Tag])) AS int)) = 1)
                                )  AS [Project6]
                            )  AS [Project6]
                            WHERE [Project6].[row_number] > 0
                            ORDER BY [Project6].[Name] ASC ) AS [Limit3]
                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[ITServers] AS [Extent18] ON [Limit3].[ITRackID] = [Extent18].[RackID]) AS [UnionAll2]
                UNION ALL
                    SELECT 
                    4 AS [C1], 
                    //code goes here
                    [Limit4].[Tag] AS [Tag], 
                    [Limit4].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], 
                    [Limit4].[timestamp1] AS [timestamp2], 
                    [Limit4].[TypeID] AS [TypeID], 
                    [Limit4].[StartDate] AS [StartDate], 
                    [Limit4].[IT360ID] AS [IT360ID], 
                    [Limit4].[IsCompleted] AS [IsCompleted], 
                    [Limit4].[PartialTag] AS [PartialTag], 
                    [Limit4].[AssetTypeID] AS [AssetTypeID], 
                    [Limit4].[Name2] AS [Name3], 
                    [Limit4].[IncludedInSearch] AS [IncludedInSearch], 
                    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C2], 
                    //code goes here
                    [Extent24].[IT360SiteID] AS [IT360SiteID1], 
                    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C32], 
                    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C33], 
                    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C34], 
                    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C35], 
                    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C36], 
                    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C37], 
                    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C38], 
                    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C39], 
                    CAST(NULL AS bigint) AS [C40], 
                    CAST(NULL AS varbinary(1)) AS [C41]
                    FROM   (SELECT TOP (15) [Project9].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID], [Project9].[DataCenterID] AS [DataCenterID], [Project9].[ZoneID] AS [ZoneID], [Project9].[timestamp] AS [timestamp], [Project9].[IT360SiteID] AS [IT360SiteID], [Project9].[TechnologyID] AS [TechnologyID], [Project9].[Tag] AS [Tag], [Project9].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], [Project9].[timestamp1] AS [timestamp1], [Project9].[TypeID] AS [TypeID], [Project9].[StartDate] AS [StartDate], [Project9].[IT360ID] AS [IT360ID], [Project9].[IsCompleted] AS [IsCompleted], [Project9].[PartialTag] AS [PartialTag], [Project9].[ID] AS [ID], [Project9].[Name] AS [Name], [Project9].[timestamp2] AS [timestamp2], [Project9].[ZoneID1] AS [ZoneID1], [Project9].[Name1] AS [Name1], [Project9].[DataCenterID1] AS [DataCenterID1], [Project9].[AssetTypeID] AS [AssetTypeID], [Project9].[Name2] AS [Name2], [Project9].[IncludedInSearch] AS [IncludedInSearch]
                        FROM ( SELECT [Project9].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID], [Project9].[DataCenterID] AS [DataCenterID], [Project9].[ZoneID] AS [ZoneID], [Project9].[timestamp] AS [timestamp], [Project9].[IT360SiteID] AS [IT360SiteID], [Project9].[TechnologyID] AS [TechnologyID], [Project9].[Tag] AS [Tag], [Project9].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], [Project9].[timestamp1] AS [timestamp1], [Project9].[TypeID] AS [TypeID], [Project9].[StartDate] AS [StartDate], [Project9].[IT360ID] AS [IT360ID], [Project9].[IsCompleted] AS [IsCompleted], [Project9].[PartialTag] AS [PartialTag], [Project9].[ID] AS [ID], [Project9].[Name] AS [Name], [Project9].[timestamp2] AS [timestamp2], [Project9].[ZoneID1] AS [ZoneID1], [Project9].[Name1] AS [Name1], [Project9].[DataCenterID1] AS [DataCenterID1], [Project9].[AssetTypeID] AS [AssetTypeID], [Project9].[Name2] AS [Name2], [Project9].[IncludedInSearch] AS [IncludedInSearch], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Project9].[Name] ASC) AS [row_number]
                            FROM ( SELECT 
                                [Extent19].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID], 
                                [Extent19].[DataCenterID] AS [DataCenterID], 
                                [Extent19].[ZoneID] AS [ZoneID], 
                                [Extent19].[timestamp] AS [timestamp], 
                                [Extent19].[IT360SiteID] AS [IT360SiteID], 
                                //code goes here
[Extent23].[IncludedInSearch] AS [IncludedInSearch]
FROM     [dbo].[ITRacks] AS [Extent19]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Technology] AS [Extent20] ON [Extent19].[ITRackID] = [Extent20].[TechnologyID]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[DataCenter] AS [Extent21] ON [Extent19].[DataCenterID] = [Extent21].[ID]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Zones] AS [Extent22] ON [Extent19].[ZoneID] = [Extent22].[ZoneID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[TechnologyTypes] AS [Extent23] ON [Extent20].[TypeID] = [Extent23].[AssetTypeID]
WHERE (@p__linq__0 IS NULL) OR (( CAST(LEN(@p__linq__0) AS int)) = 0) OR (( CAST(CHARINDEX(UPPER(@p__linq__1), UPPER([Extent20].[Tag])) AS int)) = 1)
)  AS [Project9]
)  AS [Project9]
WHERE [Project9].[row_number] > 0
ORDER BY [Project9].[Name] ASC ) AS [Limit4]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ITStorageDevices] AS [Extent24] ON [Limit4].[ITRackID] = [Extent24].[RackID]) AS [UnionAll3]
 UNION ALL
SELECT 
5 AS [C1], 
//code goes here
CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C26], 
CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C27], 
CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C28], 
CAST(NULL AS varbinary(1)) AS [C30], 
CAST(NULL AS bigint) AS [C31], 
                CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C32], 
                CAST(NULL AS decimal(8,2)) AS [C33], 
                CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C34], 
                CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C35], 
                CAST(NULL AS varbinary(1)) AS [C36], 
                CAST(NULL AS bigint) AS [C37], 
                [Extent30].[SwitchID] AS [SwitchID], 
                [Extent30].[ModelID] AS [ModelID], 
                [Extent30].[Spec] AS [Spec], 
                [Extent30].[RackID] AS [RackID], 
                [Extent30].[ConsoleServerID] AS [ConsoleServerID], 
                [Extent30].[ConsoleServerIpIn] AS [ConsoleServerIpIn], 
                [Extent30].[ConsoleServerIpOut] AS [ConsoleServerIpOut], 
                [Extent30].[Description] AS [Description], 
                [Extent30].[IT360SiteID] AS [IT360SiteID1], 
                [Extent30].[timestamp] AS [timestamp3]
                FROM   (SELECT TOP (15) [Project12].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID], [Project12].[DataCenterID] AS [DataCenterID], [Project12].[ZoneID] AS [ZoneID], [Project12].[timestamp] AS [timestamp], [Project12].[IT360SiteID] AS [IT360SiteID], [Project12].[TechnologyID] AS [TechnologyID], [Project12].[Tag] AS [Tag], [Project12].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], [Project12].[timestamp1] AS [timestamp1], [Project12].[TypeID] AS [TypeID], [Project12].[StartDate] AS [StartDate], [Project12].[IT360ID] AS [IT360ID], [Project12].[IsCompleted] AS [IsCompleted], [Project12].[PartialTag] AS [PartialTag], [Project12].[ID] AS [ID], [Project12].[Name] AS [Name], [Project12].[timestamp2] AS [timestamp2], [Project12].[ZoneID1] AS [ZoneID1], [Project12].[Name1] AS [Name1], [Project12].[DataCenterID1] AS [DataCenterID1], [Project12].[AssetTypeID] AS [AssetTypeID], [Project12].[Name2] AS [Name2], [Project12].[IncludedInSearch] AS [IncludedInSearch]
                    FROM ( SELECT [Project12].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID], [Project12].[DataCenterID] AS [DataCenterID], [Project12].[ZoneID] AS [ZoneID], [Project12].[timestamp] AS [timestamp], [Project12].[IT360SiteID] AS [IT360SiteID], [Project12].[TechnologyID] AS [TechnologyID], [Project12].[Tag] AS [Tag], [Project12].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], [Project12].[timestamp1] AS [timestamp1], [Project12].[TypeID] AS [TypeID], [Project12].[StartDate] AS [StartDate], [Project12].[IT360ID] AS [IT360ID], [Project12].[IsCompleted] AS [IsCompleted], [Project12].[PartialTag] AS [PartialTag], [Project12].[ID] AS [ID], [Project12].[Name] AS [Name], [Project12].[timestamp2] AS [timestamp2], [Project12].[ZoneID1] AS [ZoneID1], [Project12].[Name1] AS [Name1], [Project12].[DataCenterID1] AS [DataCenterID1], [Project12].[AssetTypeID] AS [AssetTypeID], [Project12].[Name2] AS [Name2], [Project12].[IncludedInSearch] AS [IncludedInSearch], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Project12].[Name] ASC) AS [row_number]
                        FROM ( SELECT 
                            //code goes here 
                            [Extent29].[IncludedInSearch] AS [IncludedInSearch]
                            FROM     [dbo].[ITRacks] AS [Extent25]
                            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Technology] AS [Extent26] ON [Extent25].[ITRackID] = [Extent26].[TechnologyID]
                            INNER JOIN [dbo].[DataCenter] AS [Extent27] ON [Extent25].[DataCenterID] = [Extent27].[ID]
                            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Zones] AS [Extent28] ON [Extent25].[ZoneID] = [Extent28].[ZoneID]
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[TechnologyTypes] AS [Extent29] ON [Extent26].[TypeID] = [Extent29].[AssetTypeID]
                            WHERE (@p__linq__0 IS NULL) OR (( CAST(LEN(@p__linq__0) AS int)) = 0) OR (( CAST(CHARINDEX(UPPER(@p__linq__1), UPPER([Extent26].[Tag])) AS int)) = 1)
                        )  AS [Project12]
                    )  AS [Project12]
                    WHERE [Project12].[row_number] > 0
                    ORDER BY [Project12].[Name] ASC ) AS [Limit5]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[ITSwitches] AS [Extent30] ON [Limit5].[ITRackID] = [Extent30].[RackID]) AS [UnionAll4]
            ORDER BY [UnionAll4].[C2] ASC, [UnionAll4].[C3] ASC, [UnionAll4].[C4] ASC, [UnionAll4].[C5] ASC, [UnionAll4].[C6] ASC, [UnionAll4].[C7] ASC, [UnionAll4].[C8] ASC, [UnionAll4].[C10] ASC, [UnionAll4].[C15] ASC, [UnionAll4].[C18] ASC, [UnionAll4].[C22] ASC, [UnionAll4].[C31] ASC, [UnionAll4].[C1] ASC',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__1 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'',@p__linq__1=N''
```

Comment: does it work if you put the Order By in the public IQueryable<ITRack> AllFindRacks_j(string q, bool forautocomplete = false) function ?

Comment: i do not want to do so as the repository method is a general purpose method ,, and will not always return ordered list..

Comment: I meant to do it just one time to see if you do not get an ordered list or not. And eventually I would watch the SQL Query just to know if you get the Order By Correctly

Comment: ifi post the generated sql statment for my query , then it will not be understood, and the generated sql i got inside the sql profiler was very long ..

Comment: You asked for help :) What I meant was look at this SQL Query and at least tell us if you see your ORDER BY somewhere

Comment: i have edited my original question with the generated sql statement